# What is the significance of this photo?

Tags: props, the-wire

In The Wire Season 2 Episode 7 "Backwash." in Frank's office there is a dart board with a black and white photo of someone.  This implies the photo is someone that Frank hates/despises.

Who is the photo of?  Why does Frank hate them?  What is the significance of including this prop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The photo is of [Robert Irsay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Irsay), an American football team owner who controversially moved the Baltimore Colts to Indianapolis in 1984, and appears to be an allegory of the situation Frank is now facing at the docks with regards to the displacement of industry.

The picture looks to be one taken by the Baltimore Sun as he clashed with reporters following the announcement.

[image: Robert Irsay shouts at reporters]

Comment: I kind of lucked out there, as a UK resident and national I know squat about American football or the nuances of Baltimore's history, but as a worshipper of 'The Wire' I am instantly drawn to any queries regarding the show - beginning by freeze framing the scene that appears to have the clearest shot of the photo (the conversation with 'Bruce DiBiago') and going from there. Its a great observation and question on your part and has allowed me the opportunity to learn the background to a wonderfully clever piece of art direction I have not queried since last going through the series.

Comment: The person he’s standing next to is William Donald Schaffer - former Maryland Governor.

Comment: Late to the party, but even if it wasn't an allegory: "*the move embittered many Baltimoreans for decades*" ([the relocation of Colts football team](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baltimore_Colts_relocation_to_Indianapolis#:~:text=The%20Baltimore%20Colts%20relocation%20to,Football%20League%20(NFL)%20season.)) and that would be enough for Frank to hate this guy though.